# encoding file as base64 string in QT with XMLRPC

Tags: qt, base64, xml-rpc

I am trying to send a file via xmlrpc as a base64 encoded string.

```
QFile sourceFile("/home/alexander/test.jpg");              

QByteArray srcRawData = sourceFile.readAll();               
QByteArray base64Encoded = srcRawData.toBase64();                        
std::string strTest(base64Encoded);

xmlrpc_c::paramList sampleAddParms;                        
sampleAddParms.add(xmlrpc_c::value_string("113957571"));   
sampleAddParms.add(xmlrpc_c::value_string(strTest));        
sampleAddParms.add(xmlrpc_c::value_string("test.jpg"));
```

When I send this to my server I get:
    Client threw error: RPC response indicates failure.  Bad parameter type  (ap_adddocument): expected base64 for parameter data, got (Python) .

This is the class definition o xmlrpc_c::value_*
http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/doc/classXmlRpc_1_1XmlRpcValue.html

I just realized I need to use the xmlrpc_c::value_bytestring() instead. How do I convert a File into a bytestring in C++? I have a ByteArray already.

I am at a loss here..

Comment: Why do you want to convert a JPG picture to string?

Comment: Because I want to send it via XML-RPC. I need to send it as base64.. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: what is the signature of `xmlrpc_c::value_bytestring()` ? is it `xmlrpc_c::value_bytestring(const char*)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems that you can use `xmlrpc_c::value_string()`

Convert your `base64` string in to a `const char*` and try. Following code should work. But still enough detail is not available in your question.

```
QFile sourceFile("/home/alexander/test.jpg");              
QByteArray base64Encoded  = sourceFile.readAll().toBase64();                                      
const char* b64Enc = QString::fromLatin1(base64Encoded).toStdString().c_str();

xmlrpc_c::paramList sampleAddParms;                        
sampleAddParms.add(xmlrpc_c::value_string("113957571"));   
sampleAddParms.add(xmlrpc_c::value_string(b64Enc));        
sampleAddParms.add(xmlrpc_c::value_string("test.jpg"));
```